# Excel Vba crashes on Worksheet("Sheet1")

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am a newbie to Excel VBA programming. So I was trying to access the a cell in the Worksheet "Sheet1" in a particular Workbook. When I type the below code, it crashes automatically.

```
Private Sub hello_click()
Worksheets("Sheet1").
```

As soon as I press ".", excel crashes showing the message "Microsoft Excel stopped working". What can be the reason for this?

Comment: And i am using excel 2013

Comment: Have you tried repairing Office. That sounds like an issue with the VBEditor.

Comment: @Rory So to repair VB Editor i should reinstall Office right?

Comment: You should be able to run a repair from Control Panel, which is a bit quicker. If that doesn't fix it then I'd suggest a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, workbooks can become corrupt without much warning, have you tried creating a new workbook with all your data in, inserting a new module and then writing your code again?

It is also convention (I believe) to name your subs as one long string with a capital for each new word. Maybe try changing the sub name to helloClick.

Comment: the `.` which causes excel to crash tries to call the properties of the Worksheets-object and doesn't care about the workbook itself. If the wb is corrupt, then "executing" code leads to errors. Also there is no real "convention" for naming.

Comment: Link to MSDN naming conventions for Visual Basic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx

Comment: You know what "suggestions" means?

Comment: @Clusks I have tried using another Workbook, but the error remains.

Comment: @Clusks when i changed it to HelloClick() also the error remains.

Comment: @DirkReichel is that the suggestions coming when you type an object, like for eg., when you type MsgBox then various options comes in yellow line color??

Comment: I'd probably go with Rory's suggestion then, as it sounds like it is something linked to the editor!

Comment: @rohitnambisan99 exactly... something crashes the whole application if it tries to access the library... if possible, I'd suggest to "repair" office (or at least excel) and if that doesn't help, then reinstall excel... :(

Comment: @Clusks Visual Basic is not the same as VBA, and naming conventions are entirely optional for either language.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ".", you do not have to place one at the end of your commands.